# Formatting Text Field As HH:MM:SS

Tags: mysql, query

I am having to `Cast()` a `Text` datatype to a `TIME` datatype.  THe issue I'm running into is when the results display i'm loosing the `hh:mm:ss` format.  The syntax I am using is `Select SUM(CAST(salestime As Time)) From testData;` How do I display my query results in `hh:mm:ss` format?  I also tried to use this syntax `SUM(Cast(Time_Format(salesTime, "%h, %i, %s") As Time))` but that is returning a whole number

**EDIT**
A few sample of the times in the `TEXT` column are:

```
0:05:58
0:00:00
0:31:54
0:23:26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`salesTime` varchar(7))
;
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`salesTime`)
VALUES
    ('0:05:58'),
    ('0:00:00'),
    ('0:31:54'),
    ('0:23:26')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(`salesTime`, "%H:%i:%s"))))  FROM Table1;

| SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(`salesTime`, "%H:%i:%s")))) |
| --------------------------------------------------------------------- |
| 01:01:18                                                              |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wUqVKNZy96RjR7hTk3md7o/14)

But TIME can only have the **maximum** of **838:59:59**, if your `SUM` get bigger, you need to convert the seconds also into `dd.hh:mm:ss`

Comment: This returns ``00:00:00`` for all of my ``SUMS()``

Comment: please add you data to show what data  salestime, i assumed that your query works.

Comment: edited to add a few times

Comment: Your cast didn't work, you i used time_Format, see example,

Answer (score 1):

you can convert hours and minutes to seconds, then sum the three totals and use the convert function to get a value in string formats or the cast function to get value in time format

```
select 
    convert(varchar, dateadd(second, z.total_hours+z.total_minutes+z.total_seconds, 0), 114) as myresult_asstring
    ,cast(dateadd(second, z.total_hours+z.total_minutes+z.total_seconds, 0) as time) as myresult_astime
from
    (
    select 
         sum(datepart(hour, m.mytime))*3600 as total_hours
        ,sum(datepart(minute, m.mytime))*60 as total_minutes
        ,sum(datepart(second, m.mytime)) as total_seconds
    from (
            select cast('0:05:58' as time) as mytime
            union
            select cast('0:00:00' as time) as mytime
            union
            select cast('0:31:54' as time) as mytime
            union
            select cast('0:23:26' as time) as mytime
        ) as m
    ) as z
```