# Create A Pivot With No SUM() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, pivot, ddl

I've seen a lot of examples using `MySQL` to create a `PIVOT` but they all use `SUM()` - using this DDL how can I create a `PIVOT` in `MySQL`

```
Create Table `data`
(
   callDate text
  ,callerName text
  ,callLength text
);

Insert Into `data` (`callDate`, `callerName`, `callLength`) Values
('07/01/2020', 'Client A', '0:00:23'),
('07/01/2020', 'Client B', '0:15:23'),
('07/01/2020', 'Client C', '0:7:10'),
('07/02/2020', 'Client A', '0:01:23'),
('07/02/2020', 'Client B', '0:12:23'),
('07/02/2020', 'Client C', '0:3:10'),
('07/03/2020', 'Client A', '0:011:23'),
('07/03/2020', 'Client B', '0:22:23'),
('07/03/2020', 'Client C', '0:23:10');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comment simply Replace the `SUM` with what ever you need in your

> ```
> Create Table `data`
> (
>    callDate text
>   ,callerName text
>   ,callLength text
> );
>
> Insert Into `data` (`callDate`, `callerName`, `callLength`) Values
> ('07/01/2020', 'Client A', '0:00:23'),
> ('07/01/2020', 'Client B', '0:15:23'),
> ('07/01/2020', 'Client C', '0:7:10'),
> ('07/02/2020', 'Client A', '0:01:23'),
> ('07/02/2020', 'Client B', '0:12:23'),
> ('07/02/2020', 'Client C', '0:3:10'),
> ('07/03/2020', 'Client A', '0:011:23'),
> ('07/03/2020', 'Client B', '0:22:23'),
> ('07/03/2020', 'Client C', '0:23:10');
> ```

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>         CONCAT(
>           'MAX(IF(callDate = "',
>           callDate,
>           '" ,`callLength`, NULL)) AS "',
>           callDate,'"'
>         )
>   ) INTO @sql
> FROM
>    `data`;
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT callerName,', @sql, ' FROM  `data` GROUP BY callerName');
>
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> callerName | 07/01/2020 | 07/02/2020 | 07/03/2020
> :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> Client A   | 0:00:23    | 0:01:23    | 0:011:23  
> Client B   | 0:15:23    | 0:12:23    | 0:22:23   
> Client C   | 0:7:10     | 0:3:10     | 0:23:10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ea22f8ac808a3e69908c53a2de876976)*

It is quite ugly and it has the same limitation as the explained [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/271683/formatting-text-field-as-hhmmss/271684#271684)

> ```
> SET @sql = NULL;
> SELECT
>     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>         CONCAT(
>           'MAX(IF(callDate = "',
>           callDate,
>           '" ,`callLength`, NULL)) AS "',
>           callDate,'"'
>         )
>   ) INTO @sql
>   FROM
>    `data`;
>   SET @sql2 = NULL;
>   SELECT
>     GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
>         CONCAT(
>           'SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(IF(callDate = "',
>           callDate,
>           '" ,`callLength`, NULL), "%H:%i:%s")))) AS "',
>           callDate,'"'
>         )
>   ) INTO @sql2
> FROM
>    `data`;
> SELECT @sql2;
> SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT callerName,', @sql, ' FROM  `data` GROUP BY callerName UNION SELECT "total",',@sql2,' FROM  `data`');
> PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
> EXECUTE stmt;
> DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
> ```
>
> ```
> | @sql2                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
> | :---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(IF(callDate = "07/01/2020" ,`callLength`, NULL), "%H:%i:%s")))) AS "07/01/2020",SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(IF(callDate = "07/02/2020" ,`callLength`, NULL), "%H:%i:%s")))) AS "07/02/2020",SEC_TO_TIME( SUM( TIME_TO_SEC(TIME_FORMAT(IF(callDate = "07/03/2020" ,`callLength`, NULL), "%H:%i:%s")))) AS "07/03/2020" |
>
> callerName | 07/01/2020 | 07/02/2020 | 07/03/2020
> :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :---------
> Client A   | 0:00:23    | 0:01:23    | 0:011:23  
> Client B   | 0:15:23    | 0:12:23    | 0:22:23   
> Client C   | 0:7:10     | 0:3:10     | 0:23:10   
> total      | 00:22:56   | 00:16:56   | 00:56:56
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d18c9fb0019f2c6fcca8dd0b6e6e33b5)*